# how to stop worker threads when work is done in one of them?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having simple simulation that acts like cracking a hash now I want all the other workers to stop when one of them finds the result? Is there any way other than stop because that is deprecated?

```
import java.util.Random;

class Worker extends Thread{
int target,start,current,end;

public Worker(int target, int start, int end) {
    super();
    this.target = target;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    current=start;
    while(target!=current){
        System.out.println("Not found  target at "+current);
        current++;
        if(current==end){
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(target==current){
        System.out.println(target+" found");
    }
}

}
public class RandomBreak {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r=new Random(100);
    int target=r.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println("trying to search "+target);

    Worker w1=new Worker(target,1,30);
    Worker w2=new Worker(target,30,60);
    Worker w3=new Worker(target,60,90);
    Worker w4=new Worker(target,90,100);
    w1.start();
    w2.start();
    w3.start();
    w4.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When one thread finds the answer, call Thread.interrupt() on other threads. When you catch InterruptedException, exit the worker thread.

If your "real" code does not have thread.sleep(), then simply check for the Thread interrupt flag occasionally, something like:

```
if( Thread.interrupted() ) {
   throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a common data structure to store a flag and pass same instance of the data structure to each worker thread. The worker who finds the target would set the flag before exiting. Check the flag in your while loop along with target. Code snippet:

```
public WorkStatus {
    private volatile boolean completed;

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public synchronized void markCompleted(boolean completed) {
        this.completed = completed;
    }
}

public Worker implements Runnable {

    .
    .
    private WorkStatus workStatus;

    public Worker(int target, int start, int end, WorkStatus workStatus) {
       .
       .
       this.workStatus = workStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       .
       while(!workStatus.isCompleted() && target!=current) {
           .

       }

       if(target==current) {
           workStatus.markCompleted(true);
           .
       }
    }
}
```

Make sure you pass same instance of WorkStatus to all Worker instances.

Answer (score 0):

make a loop that starts the thread and adds it to a list, 
when the answer is found you can then iterate through the list stopping the other threads. 
If you use a thread pool you will be able to use ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()
to stop all remaining threads in the pool.

Comment: how would the main thread will know that which of the thread has found the item or just terminated because it crossed its limit. how can I signal this to the main server

Comment: you set a callback that the thread that finds the answer then calls the callback to terminate itself and its siblings

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to stop the execution of a thread is to use interrupts and implement the interrupt handling yourself. You can use `Thread.interrupt()` to change the interrupt status of the thread  and `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to check if the thread is interrupted.
In your case the code could look something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Worker extends Thread {
    int target, start, current, end;

public Worker(final int target, final int start, final int end) {
    super();
    this.target = target;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    current = start;
    while (target != current && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        System.out.println("Not found  target at " + current);
        current++;
        if (current == end) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (target == current) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println(target + " found");
    }
  }
}
```

The Worker thread would search for the given number and repeatedly check if the Thread was interrupted. If the thread is interrupted then that  means that another thread has found the number. In case that the thread finds the number it is looking for, then it calls `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to signal to the main method that the number was found and to terminate other worker threads.
The main method would look like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random(100);
    int target = r.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println("trying to search " + target);

    Worker w1 = new Worker(target, 1, 30);
    Worker w2 = new Worker(target, 30, 60);
    Worker w3 = new Worker(target, 60, 90);
    Worker w4 = new Worker(target, 90, 100);
    w1.start();
    w2.start();
    w3.start();
    w4.start();

    while (true) {
        if (w1.isInterrupted() || w2.isInterrupted() || w3.isInterrupted() || w4.isInterrupted()) {
            w1.interrupt();
            w2.interrupt();
            w3.interrupt();
            w4.interrupt();
            break;
        } else if (!w1.isAlive() && !w2.isAlive() && !w3.isAlive() && !w4.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid search number.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the main method we repeatedly check if one of the threads is interrupted. If it is then interrupt the other threads and end the execution. The other part of the if clause`if (!w1.isAlive() && !w2.isAlive() && !w3.isAlive() && !w4.isAlive())` is a safety check if the user gives a number that the threads don't look for. If the all the threads have finished the execution and the number was not found then end the program.